# jest react django rest test implementation

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Rookie question. I have the code below, for which I'd like to create a test case.

```
class APIInstanceView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  instanceData: [],
                    apiData: [],
                    mode: "loading",
    };
}

componentDidMount() {

    let insturl = DJANGOURL_rest_apis_instance_api.replace('__API__',this.props.api)
    let apiurl = DJANGOURL_rest_apis_one.replace('__API__',this.props.api)

    $.when(
        $.get(apiurl),
        $.get(insturl)
    ).then(function (api, instance) {

    }.bind(this),
    function(){
        // ERROR
    }.bind(this))
}
```

When running jest with the code below

```
describe('APIInstanceView', () => {

it('change api instance view based on state', () => {
    // Render a checkbox with label in the document
    const menu = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <APIInstanceView />
    );
```

});

});

I get a ReferenceError: DJANGOURL_rest_apis_instance_api is not defined.

How and where should I define the DJANGOURL_rest_apis_instance_api ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try adding `window.DJANGOURL_rest_apis_instance_api = 'something';` before renderIntoDocument.